# Transposing table in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table that in principle looks like this (the actual one has many more observations):

[image]

And I would like that the end result looks like this:

[image]

I am not sure how to even start with constructing the table so that it has a doubleheader....

Comment: In what medium are you hoping to output this table? Are you doing Rmarkdown to HTML or Word or PDF? Or something else?

Comment: for now I would like to manipulate it as a dataframe. Then I am thinking to create three tables (one for each topX) with gt with the percentage changes from one period to another

Comment: Data frames don't have multiple headers, so I'd suggest rethinking that.

Comment: You could `pivot_wider` the table to encode both sets of information in a single header, with column names like `top4_1999`, `top10_1999`, etc. If you're interested in that, check out the [reshape from long to wide FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/903061). There's many methods, I'd recommend the `pivot_wider` approach.